# Network is unreachable message even when I am able to ping next hop address

Tags: linux, networking, routing

main routing table on my linux box looks like this

```
[root@hng1 ~]# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
9.9.9.0         0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth4
10.41.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth3
10.61.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         10.61.0.1       0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

I am able to ping address 10.41.41.228

```
[root@hng1 ~]# ping 10.41.41.228
PING 10.41.41.228 (10.41.41.228) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.41.41.228: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=3.55 ms
64 bytes from 10.41.41.228: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=1.68 ms
```

But not able to add a route to an address with the next hop as the above address

```
[root@hng1 ~]# ip route add 20.20.20.1/32 via 10.41.41.228 dev eth3
RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable
```

What am I missing??

Comment: 10.41.41.228 doesn’t have a route to 20.20.20.1.

Answer (score 0):

We can try ping:

ping -a **IP address of eth3 network card** 10.41.41.228.

If we can ping, it goes through eth3. Then we need to set the gateway of eth3 as 10.41.41.228.

If we can not ping, it goes through eth0, the next hop of eth3 is not 10.41.41.228.